# Should I enclose validation functions in try-except and re-raise exceptions?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a validation function such as:

```
def validate(value):
    if value <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Only positive values are allowed")
```

Then, in my code, should I use it directly:

```
def my_function(val1, val2):
    validate(val1)
    validate(val2)
```

or, should I enclose both (or each) function in a try-except block and re-raise `ValueError` exception from the validation function:

```
def my_function(val1, val2):
    try:
        validate(val1)
        validate(val2)
    except:
        raise
```

Which approach is better from whatever point of view (i.e., style, PEP8, Pythonicisism)?

I prefer the first approach, but I've seen how others are using this validation function and it is the second approach. I am trying to understand if I am missing something here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to catch an exception only to reraise it. The only people who do so are incorrigible C programmers who don't like the idea of exceptions bubbling through layers of the stack that don't acknowledge they might be raised (the same folks who keep writing `for i in range(len(someseq)):` and accessing `someseq[i]` over and over instead of using Pythonic iteration styles). But they're fighting the language here; allowing exceptions to bubble through layers that don't acknowledge them isn't a matter of personal style to argue over, it's how the language was designed.

In an exception-based language, you only catch exceptions if you have something useful to do with them. This can include reraising after taking some other action, or raising a more specific or different exception if you have the context to determine a better exception, but it's never just "catch 'em all, reraise 'em immediately". That's pointlessly verbose, and makes the code slower (even on success pathways, as `try` blocks involve a small amount of setup/teardown overhead even when no exception is raised) to no benefit.

Comment: I would say that a possibly good reason to catch the `ValueError` is maybe to raise a different, more descriptive `ValueError` if the validation was not this straightforward.

Comment: @modesitt: I think that's covered under "raising a more specific or different exception if you have the context to determine a better exception". Either way though, it wouldn't work here, where two identical `ValueError`s could be raised, but with both in the same `try` block, you couldn't distinguish them when you caught them.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't do anything after the `except` instruction, "trying" doesn't make sense.
It's just more code for nothing, keep your code simple.

Then you shouldn't use bare `except:`, but rather `except ValueError:` to be sure that the exception only catches that specific use case, and not things like `KeyboardInterrupt` or anything else...